# Determining type of Haskell function

Tags: haskell

One past exam question was to state the type of the function `ring` with definition `ring r q p = r (q p)`. Supposedly the answer is `ring :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`, but I don't see where this comes from. Surely such a type would indicate that `ring` only receives two arguments, but in the definition it takes three, so what's going on?

Comment: that's equivalent to `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, which has your 3 arguments. Remember that strictly speaking *all* Haskell functions only take 1 argument, all functions which appear to take more only do so because of currying.

Comment: Every function in Haskell takes *one* parameter.

Comment: The type `a -> (b -> c)` is more verbose than `a -> b -> c` but the same.

Comment: Strictly speaking, each function takes exactly one argument. Loosely speaking, your `ring` can (appear to) take arbitrarily many arguments (of the right types), e.g. `ring id id (+) 4 5 = id (id (+)) 4 5 = (+) 4 5 = 9`. Number of arguments is often an illusion (albeit a convenient one, most of the times).

Comment: Note you can rewrite `ring` equivalently several different ways: `ring r q = \p -> r (q p)`, or `ring r = \q -> \p -> r (q p)`, or `ring = \r -> \q -> \p -> r (q p)`.

Answer (score 5):

Every function in Haskell takes *one* parameter. A function can however return a function that takes another parameter. Haskell however introduces some syntax to make it more convenient. A signature `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)` is thus equivalent to `(b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))` or `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`.

Let us first analyze the expression:

```
ring r q p = r (q p)
```

Since at the moment we do not know much about the type yet, we will first assign some types to the parameters:

```
r :: a
q :: b
p :: c
ring :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

Now we can start to determine the types. In the expression, we see `q p`, this thus means that `q` is a function, and `p` a parameter. This thus means that `q` is a function of type `c -> e` (with `e` a type parameter we introduce).

So we derived that:

```
q :: c -> e
p :: c
q p :: e
```

Next we see that the result of `q p` is used as a parameter with `r` the function, so that means `r` is a function that takes an `e` as parameter type. We thus set the type of `r` to `e -> f`. We thus know that:

```
q p :: e
r :: e -> f
r (q p) :: f
```

Since the result of `ring r q p` is `r (q p)`, this thus means that the type of `ring` is:

```
ring :: (e -> f) -> (c -> e) -> c -> f
```

or more verbose:

```
ring :: (e -> f) -> ((c -> e) -> (c -> f))
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's go step by step into you `ring` function (known for everybody as `compose` or `.`)

here is the story:

```
ring r q p = r (q p)
```

if you start with `p` you can give to it a type, the variable is not bounded or restricted, so it can be variable, generic, so let's choose a name, `a`

```
p :: a
```

now, `q` has something that you can tell, it takes values of type `p` as parameter, right? Because it is applied to `p` , `(q p)`, so, `q` is a function, and a function has the form (type -> type),

```
p :: a
q :: (type -> type)
```

now you can replace the input, `q` expects a `p` typed values, and `p :: a` so:

```
p :: a
q :: a -> type
```

again, the type of the return can be the same as the input, but is not restricted to be, so we can use another name to it, let use `b`

```
p :: a
q :: a -> b
(q p) :: b
```

now, what about `r` ?, `r` expects the result of `(q p)` and you know the type, it is `b`, same logic, `r :: type -> type` because it is a function

```
p :: a
q :: a -> b
(q p) :: b
r :: b -> type
```

and finally, the return type of `r` is not restricted, so it can be a `c` type, so:

```
p :: a
q :: a -> b
(q p) :: b
r :: b -> c
r (q p) :: c
```

replacing everything in `ring`:

```
ring :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
ring r q p = r (q p)
```

see that I didn't use the final parenthesis, because they are not needed, in haskell the functions are curried, so, its true that if you give two functions to ring, it will return a third function of type  `a -> c`

let's see:

```
ring show (+1)

(+1) :: Num a -> a -> a
show :: Show a => a -> String

ring show (+1) :: (Show a, Num a) => a -> String
```

and I didn't give the value, so that why you can write ring as:

```
ring :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

and remove it to:

```
ring :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

and to see more, check the types of:

```
ring show :: Show a => (b -> a) -> b -> String
ring show (+1) :: (Show a, Num a) => a -> String
ring  show (+1) 2 :: String
```

ring also can have more extra parenthesis:

```
ring :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
```

as you can see in `ring show` it returns `((a -> b) -> (a -> c))` and `ring show (+1)` returns `(a -> c)`